# Launch fullscreen Chrome from Android home screen without statusbar

Tags: javascript, android, html, google-chrome, fullscreen

I have a customer that wants to launch a certain website from an icon on a tablet that runs Android. He's leasing out the tablets, so we have complete control over the hardware. The idea is that these tablets will *only* be used for his site (it's a type of slide show), so he wants the tablet home screen to have a single icon, and that icon will always launch his site in complete fullscreen. This works somewhat, but the statusbar does not go away without a user gesture. On Chrome the meta tag *mobile-web-app-capable* does the trick, but we can also use other browsers if this simplifies things. Is it possible to remove the statusbar without a second user gesture (the first being launching the website)?

And in response to the answers below, how can a WebLauncherActivity be useful when the user is just opening a browser?

Comment: make a full screen activity, put a webview inside it, that will work i think

Answer (score 1):

On the page, `element.requestFullscreen()` displays the element in fullscreen mode.

Additional JS API and CSS selectors can provide other fullscreen specification in the following html5 article:
[Building an Amazing Fullscreen Mobile Experience](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/fullscreen/)

Comment: This is exactly what I describe in my question that *doesn't* work.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `WebappLauncherActivity` that's used by the page shortcuts.
You should be able to launch the activity via `adb` with:

`adb shell am start -n com.android.chrome/.webapps.WebappManager.ACTION_START_WEBAPP "url"`

You can also add your own activity inheriting from FullscreenActivity which is the base for WebappActivity like mentioned by @tushar-pandey.

Comment: Will this really work? I already got it to start in semi-fullscreen, like described in the question, but the statusbar prevails. Browser standards want to ensure that fullscreen is a result of a user action (like the pressing of a button + javascript), but there is no way to trigger javascript from FullscreenActivity, I think. Triggering requestFullscreen() on any other event than a user action results in a browser error.